# Call Angularjs module once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and have seemingly a simple task.
I want to reuse the AngluarJS [LocalStorageModule](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) 
on an empty page (no UI, execute once and redirect).

Here's how my attempt looks like:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.js"></script>
<script>
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'LocalStorageModule' ])
 .factory(
   function(localStorageService) {
    
    localStorageService.set('username', 'some-user');
    localStorageService.set('token', 'somevalue'));
    window.location = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname
      + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '');
   });
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">You are being redirected
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, the factory function is not being called.
If I replace factory with the config the function is getting called but the localStorageServiceProvider doesn't expose set() method that I need.

The purpose of my exercise is to store value in the local browser storage for the real AngularJS application where the browser gets redirected to right after the above code gets executed, so that it can read and use the stored value.

Comment: I can't say that I understand your question properly but if I am you firstly need the normal `.config()` so the module injector can inject the `LocalStorageModule`. Afterwards you can use `.run()` to run the code that you need to run once. Also, use `$location` for redirection and such. Remember to inject `$location` and `LocalStorageFactory` into the `.run()` function call. The `.factory()` function is used to create your own factories, not to reuse the existing modules/factories.

Comment: @AleksandarBencun I don't get localStorageModule injected into the .config(). I get localStorageModuleProvider instead. That's different things I guess.
Why $location is preferrable vs. my approach? This is not a real AngularJS app if you notice, I'm just trying to reuse an AngularJS module.
Thanks for the hint with .run(), will take a look.

Comment: Well, the documentation clearly states that you need to use `var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['LocalStorageModule']);` for initial module injection. Afterwards you need to use `localStorageServiceProvider` when injecting the module inside functions, e.g. `.run(function(localStorageServiceProvider){/*code*/});`

Comment: Ok, but localStorageServiceProvider doesn't allow storing values, i.e. it doesn't expose set() method.
Is the .run() approach irrelevant then?

Comment: If it's not exposing it then yes, it is irrelevant. You can try creating a JSFiddle so we can take a better look at your issue.

Comment: Hey @AleksandarBencun! Looks like you are right!
I can inject localStorageService into run() and it gets called in the way as you provided in the deleted post. Bring it back so that I can upvote it :)

Comment: I brought the answer back with some more details on prefix setting so that  the app that you are redirecting to can read the data. Glad to help!
I'd like to add that I made a mistake, `localStorageServiceProvider` is used for configuration and the `localStorageService` is used for actually working with this module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the module, configure it, and use it afterwards.

```
//load and config the modules
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [ 'LocalStorageModule' ]);
myApp.config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
  localStorageServiceProvider
    .setPrefix('samePrefixAsTheTargetApp');
});
//this function is called only once
myApp.run(function(localStorageService){
  localStorageService.set('username', 'some-user');
  localStorageService.set('token', 'somevalue'));
  window.location = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname
                    + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you would want to do is use ngStorage module and its factories  $localStorage and  $sessionStorage to save data locally on browser.

Then before redirecting save value:

```
$sessionStorage.someVal ="blah"
```

and after redirect, read it:

```
$scope.val = $sessionStorage.someVal
```

Comment: My main application is using the LocalStorageModule. That's the reason why I'm trying use it, it's to provide maximum compliance.
Are you saying that the ngStorage module is 100% compatible with the LocalStorageModule?
(I can't touch the main application)

Comment: as per docs "If localStorage is not supported, the library will default to cookies instead. This behavior can be disabled." Have u checked if any cookies are getting set with names ?

Comment: I don't think he's using the ngStorage. This a different library linked in the OP.

Comment: Exactly, I want to store values with the same library/module that will read them a millisecond later after redirect.

Comment: One other fail safe alternative is use $cookies provided by angular

Comment: As I understand, the main purpose of the LocalStorageModule is to provide automatic fallback to cookies vs local storage.
I don't want to play with that logic and reimplement it, just reuse existing library.

Comment: Well, in your last post edit you are using sessionStorage, which is different from the local storage altogether, as I heard.

Comment: unfortunately localstorage doesn't have widespread browser support, that why library itself uses cookiesas fall back. So after redirection happens, check if any cookies are set with same name using either $cookies  of your angular or your developer tools